# Joomla session variable not found in a php

Tags: php, session, joomla

I am setting a session variable in an Article:

```
 $session->set('test' , 'testing' );
```

As long as I stay within other Joomla modules and articles I can read it without problem.

```
$db = $session->get('test' , '' );
```

But when I execute a php that is called by a XMLHttpRequest within a Javascript (everything in the same folder), it doesnt find the session variable and returns the default value.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you get if you do var_dump($_SESSION); in your php script? Just wondering if joomla is calling the variable something else ( like jsession[test] for example...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare those session values are variables you can read from anywhere in Joomla you should be using the setUserState and getUserState methods.

For example if you want to set a session variable named test your could do this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setUserState('test','my test value');
```

Then if you want to call that anywhere else in Joomla just set it to a variable using getUserState like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$mySessionVariable = $app->getUserState('test');
echo $mySessionVariable;
```

Here is a link to the session state variables documentation for Joomla:
[Joomla User State Variables](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables)

Comment: Doesnt work. Looks like session variables are not available in my php. As long as I am strictly within Joomla (all php in Articles & Modules) it is fine. But when I call a php from within a Javascript they are not there

Comment: Can you post some of the javascript and you you are trying to call it?

Comment: var sel = "/joomla/viewyourtariffs.php?ac=tarifffilter";
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
xmlhttp.open("GET", sel, false);

xmlhttp.send();
respglob = xmlhttp.responseText;

alert(respglob);